# How to disable Firefox URL correction

Tags: firefox

1. I have visited working url: https://www.xyz/my_working_url.php
2. Then I have visited non working url https://www.xyz/my_working_url_B.php
3. Page is redirected to https://www.xyz/my_working_url.php
4. After creating my_working_url_B.php I am still redirected to my_working_url.php

Answer (score 0):

You have to set

`browser.fixup.alternate.enabled` in `about:config` to **false**.